# Introducing Dragons to Attack Composition

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have my TH at lvl 7. Already upgraded a barrack so now I can train dragons.

My question is:

As I can hold 180 troops (9 dragons), how can I make a good composition to attack villages of my same level with maxed defenses?

I'm currently using 1 healer, 2 wallbreakers, 17 archers, 8 barbarians, 13 wizards and 17 giants. But I want to introduce dragons to that comp, or maybe use all dragons?

I'm very confused as now I have a lot of options.

Comment: Would the attack be for Clan Wars (target 100% destruction) or getting Gold/Elixirs (target the resources)?

Comment: getting stars, 100%

Comment: Time to spend some elixir on those army camps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about TH7 level 1 dragon attack strategy for clan wars, with objective of 100% destruction (3-star) against a TH7 maxed defense, then army composition should be either:

1. 9 level 1 dragons, 3 lightning spells and 1 level 1+ dragon in Clan Castle or
2. 9 level 1 dragons, 3 lightning spells and 4 level 5+ balloons in Clan Castle.

As said by MetxChris in [The Definitive TH7/8 Dragon Guide For Clan Wars (21 Videos)](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/508826-The-Definitive-TH7-8-Dragon-Guide-For-Clan-Wars):

> Regarding dragon attacks in war, our clan expects its members to
>   always be able to 3-star any TH7, even when only using lvl1 dragons

Comment: First, TH7 people can only have a level three clan castle, which holds 20 space not 25. Next, he only has 180 space so he can only hold nine drags max.

Comment: TQ. Editing that in.

Comment: Why level 5 balloons, not 5+ which includes 6?

Comment: Yep 5+, would be better. Editing that in.

Comment: For the effective result, Make your army camp space 200, So you can hold 10 Dragons. And upgrade your Dragon to level 2 which is possible in TH7. Take Max Balloon(lvl6) in CC + Three lightning spell. This will give three star any TH7 base.